# laravel8 jetstream & fortify. want to set different redirection after register and login

Tags: laravel-8, fortify, laravel-jetstream

i found
'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,
in config/fortify.php

what i want to do is

when user completed register user, redirect to /user/complete

when user logged in, redirect to /dashboard

now, both of them redirect to /dashboard

(strictly when after completed register user, redirect to login because not logged in yet)

how can i set route properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do this before but maybe can customize a little declaring another path in the fortify config file

```
'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,
'register' => RouteServiceProvider::REGISTER;
```

In the RouteServiceProvider class

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
public const REGISTER = '/user/complete';
```

and in the RegisterResponse class

```
: redirect(config('fortify.register'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add next code to `config/fortify.php`:

```
    'redirects' => [
        'login' => null,
        'logout' => null,
        'password-confirmation' => null,
        'register' => null,
        'email-verification' => '/firstvisit',
        'password-reset' => null,
    ],
```

Response with redirection which generated by Fortify uses this values. For more information check `laravel\fortify\src\Http\Responses\` directory. For example:

```
namespace Laravel\Fortify\Http\Responses;

use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
            : redirect()->intended(Fortify::redirects('login'));
    }
}
```

`redirect()->intended(Fortify::redirects('login'))` - this method tries to read value from session `'url.intended'` and if it null - uses value passed as first argument.